# Volume of liquid in a sphere without calculus

Tags: geometry

A hemispherical bowl with a $r$-cm radius contains some water, which is $h$ cm deep. What is the volume of this water?

I can find the radius of the water at each depth $h$ which gives me the area at each depth. This area is $(2rh-h^2)\pi$. Taking the integral of this easily gives me a formula for the volume. Is there a way to do this without calculus? I know I'm supposed to get $\pi h^2(r-\frac{1}{3}h)$ but I don't know how to get there without an integral. I did enough calculations to convince myself that filling the sphere to some depth doesn't make a partial sphere. Is there another way to express the volume of a hemisphere?

Comment: See [this](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Apostol496-508.pdf); in particular, Section 2.

Comment: Oh that's perfect. A hemisphere with radius $r$ has the same volume as a cylinder with height and radius $r$ minus the volume of a cone inscribed in it. Thanks!

Comment: That's very helpful. I didn't realize that Cavalieri's principle had a name--it was just something I was intuitively assuming was true! I can definitely see how this is just a pre-cursor to integration.

Comment: I deleted the comment. I'm not sure exactly how Archimedes proved the result (in particular the version of Cavalieri's principle used) mentioned in my previous link. (I suspect his exhaustion method lurks somewhere within though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressing the surface area at every depth is a very good start. It is

$$(2rh-h^2)\pi=\pi r^2-\pi(r-h)^2$$

so you can also see this as the area of an annulus with outer radius $r$ and inner radius $\lvert r-h\rvert$. Due to [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), two bodies have equal volume if they have equal area in every horizontal cross section.

So the sphere has equal volume to the body formed by these annuly, which is a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $2r$ from which two circular cones have been cut away, each with a base of radius $r$ and a height $r$, so they have their bases in common with the caps of the cylinder and their apexes meet in the center.

But you can just as well use that same principle for a segment of a sphere. So to compute its volume, you simply have to express the correct combination of cylinders and cones, and you are done. If you have elementary formulas for these, then you can do this without resorting to integrals.

Of course, Cavalieri's principle has some resemblance to rules you know from integral calculus. Nevertheless, it is more intuitive to understand, and it is a lot older.